# How to run bash commands from pwsh?

Tags: bash, powershell

We have a powershell script which is 99% cross-platform but occasionally we need an IF LINUX THEN branch because of how different windows and linux service management is.

We would like to run the `kill` command from bash but this is an alias of the powershell `Stop-Process`.

How do we run native bash commands like `ps`, `kill` and `ls` from Powershell.

Note `sh ps` or `bash ps` do not work.

```
PS > bash ps
/usr/bin/ps: /usr/bin/ps: cannot execute binary file
```

Comment: If you run kill prefixed with a \ and so \kill, it will by pass any aliases and run the executable.

Comment: What about `bash ./path/to/script/that/calls/ps.sh`

Comment: @RamanSailopal That's true of bash but not of pwsh. Running `\kill` inside powershell fails with CommandNotFoundException.

Answer (score 1):

Had lots of trouble running `ant -version` from pwsh but this works:

```
Invoke-Expression "/bin/bash ant -version"
```

### Cross-Platform Function

```
function RunCommand($Command) {
  if($env:OS -eq 'Windows_NT') {
    CMD /c $Command 
  } else {
    Invoke-Expression "/bin/bash $Command"
  }
}
```

Comment: There's really no need to go round via cmd on Windows, doesn't `& $Command` work?

Comment: No, that doesn't work - it always searches the PowerShell aliases before it looks at the PATH. Create an "iwr.cmd" on your path and try run it from powershell without CMD.

Comment: Ah I didn't think further because I saw `ant` and that's not an alias normally. Still, if you need the distinction you can use `& (Get-Command $Command -CommandType Application)` instead of going round via cmd

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that running `bash` runs bash from pwsh, you would want `bash -c "ps"`. Normally the argument to bash would be a script that it tries to execute, hence the error "cannot exxecute binary file". `ps` is not a bash script, but an executable binary. The `-c` on the other hand runs arbitrary bash code provided as a command line argument, which can obviously run programs like `ps`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the location of the command you can just run it:

```
/usr/bin/kill

Usage:
  kill [options] <pid|name]...
...
```

Otherwise `which` can find it and run it with `Invoke-Expression` or `iex`:

```
which kill | iex
```

This can get tricky since `which` could return multiple lines which you then would have to guess and just take the first one. You also need to somehow add parameters (e.g. `123`) to your command:

```
which kill | select -first 1 | % {iex "$_ 123"}

kill: sending signal to 123 failed: No such process
```